# How to change the priority of service in run levels on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, service, samba, runlevel

I have tried to change the priority of samba on run level 2 by renaming the S16samaba to S21samba.

```
mv S16samaba S21samaba
```

But when I reboot the server it starts before other services which are low priority like S12ntp.

I have also tried using update-rc.d command.

```
update-rc.d samba start 80 2 3 4 5
```

This command renamed S21samba back to S16samba. And it doesn't work.

I want to start the samba after all other services are started.

Please give me suggestion with the idea of priority of service in run levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your approaches do not work it that they assume a system V init. Ubuntu  does not use system V init. It either uses upstart or systemd depending on version. I do not believe either system uses run levels which is a tragic step back for such "advanced" systems.

Answer (score 1):

This from Debian Wiki
https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot

> To do this, in Debian you currently need to talk to the maintainer of
>   packages with scripts Z and X, asking one of them (or both) to move
>   their script into a different number. Dependency based boot sequencing
>   make it possible for each package maintainer to specify the
>   dependencies of its scripts, and leave the number allocation to the
>   dependency resolver.

hildred's answer doesn't make sense to me if it means that runlevels have been superseded in more advanced initialization designs.